# How to send POST request using html button

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to send post request using html button. I know it is easily done by jQuery ajax, but i do not want to use jquery and ajax. How can i do it?

This my function

```
public function editProduct() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        echo 'You are authorized';
    } else {
        echo 'You are not authorized to access this page.';
    }
}
```

This is my HTML button

```
<button type="submit" onclick="location.href = '<?=base_url().'company/admin/add_product/editProduct?>';">Send Post Request</button>
```

Comment: you can use <form action="post.php"> you can the post data from post.php file

Comment: Can any option other than form and jquery?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank u sir. I will remember your suggestion for next time.

Answer (score 3):

In your form tag, just write a method="post"

```
<form method="post">
 ...
    <button type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Remove the onclick property and add the url to your form action

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do this:

1. via form (best method):

   ```
   <form action ="<?php echo base_url().'company/admin/add_product/editProduct'?>" method="post">
         <input type="submit" value="Send Post Request">
   </form>
   ```
2. via javascript (jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ )

Comment: can i do any option other than form or jquery?

Comment: Use GET method it is possible

Comment: where is use GET method?

Comment: You can't use GET to make a POST request.

Comment: jQuery is just a library. It's Ajax stuff (at least the bit that does POST) is just a wrapper around the XMLHttpRequest object, which you can use directly.